# Python creating static objects which are shared amongst all class objects

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a class node something like this. It's a typical node object for a graph.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, edges = []):
        super(Node, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.edges = edges
        self.visited = False

    def addEdge(self, *args):
        print(self)
        self.edges.extend(args)
        print(self.edges)
```

I create two objects like this -

```
one = Node(1)
two = Node(2)
```

Next I add a pointer of `two` to `one` using the `addEdge` method defined above -

```
one.addEdge(two)
```

Now comes the surprising bit. When I check the values of `one.edges` and `two.edges` I get this -

> one.edges
>   [<**main**.Node object at 0x109ed3e50>]
>
> two.edges
>   [<**main**.Node object at 0x109ed3e50>].

If you see both the objects have gotten the value. I'm quite puzzled at this and have no idea why this is happening. Is this how python behaves? If so can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry. Updated it. It was one.addEdge(two)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful when using an array literal as a default value because you don't get a new array with each instance — you get a reference to the same one. In your example you will see:

```
>> one.edges is two.edges
True
```

You need to do something to make sure you get a new array each time. One things you can do is:

```
self.edges = list(edges)
```

Another option is:

```
def __init__(self, data, edges = None):

   if edges is None:
        self.edges = []
   else:
        self.edges = edges
```

But `edges` is still mutable so it may also lead to subtle bugs if the caller is not expecting it to be changed.

Comment: So this `edges=[]` in the init method is the culprit?

Comment: Yes, many will say it's a bad idea to use mutable objects as default parameters.

Comment: Ok. That was unexpected. Does the same happen when we pass {} literals as default parameters?

Comment: Yes, @RajKumar the same thing will happen.